# Как сменить язык в PSQL Shell

Tags: sql, postgresql, shell, psql

Как сменить язык в PSQL Shell я хочу что бы все выводило на английском языке, но не могу ни как найти как сменить язык с украинского на английский.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Пожалуйста, попробуйте следующую команду:

```
SET lc_messages TO 'en_US.UTF-8';
```

или же

```
setx LC_MESSAGES English /m
```

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/CYiiWQx.png так как хотелось бы. Пишет что установило но присылает сообщение на той локализации на которой сам ПК. Когда я сменил локализацию системы на Английскую то все заработало так как нужно, но мне нужен ПК на языке который и так сейчас. а psql на Английском.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191428/change-language-of-system-and-error-messages-in-postgresql

Comment: https://imgur.com/65Y1YEI Та и сам postresql.conf уже имеет такие значение и все равно в cmd он выводит на локале системы